# Creating a list from a specific column in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following dataset address 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/Visualization/Online_Retail/Online_Retail.csv'

I used the following code to import

```
online_rt = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/07_Visualization/Online_Retail/Online_Retail.csv', delimiter = ',')
online_rt.head()
```

and this code to filter out some specific datapoints

```
Quantity_sum = online_rt.groupby(['Country'])[['Quantity']].sum().sort_values('Quantity', ascending=False)

Top_10 = Quantity_sum.iloc[1:11,:]
```

Now what I want is to convert the Country column to a separate list and the Quantity column to a separate list

I used

`Top_10['Country'].tolist()` for one column

and

`Top_10['Quantity'].tolist()` for the other column

but it keeps giving me KeyError :

> 'Country' for the 1st list and KeyError: 'Quantity' for the second
>   list

How can I make two seperate lists for my data??

Answer (score 0):

After the `groupby` the resulting dataframe `Quantity_sum` has only one column: `Quantity`, while the `Country` column is the index now.

```
In [66]: Quantity_sum.head()
Out[66]:
                Quantity
Country
United Kingdom   4263829
Netherlands       200128
EIRE              142637
Germany           117448
France            110480
```

In order to get list of countries you have to access it through the `index` attribute of the dataframe, like so:

```
In [67]: Top_10.index.tolist()
Out[67]:
['Netherlands',
 'EIRE',
 'Germany',
 'France',
 'Australia',
 'Sweden',
 'Switzerland',
 'Spain',
 'Japan',
 'Belgium']
```

And for `Quantity` what you have done seems correct and works for me:

```
In [68]: Top_10['Quantity'].tolist()
Out[68]: [200128, 142637, 117448, 110480, 83653, 35637, 30325, 26824, 25218, 23152]
```

Comment: Cheers! Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you :)